# Migration failure to Unix StackExchange

Tags: bug, status-completed

I tried migrating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975647/shell-script-execution-on-multiple-servers#question) to the Unix Stackexchange site, and I got the "Workin on ur Problems" page.  When that happened three times, I gave up and did a normal off-topic close.

You can see on that page the problem.  I'm now four people. :)

**Edit:** Reopened the question, so the user could get an answer to his question.  You can see the problem in the edit history.  Note that the question already had two close votes and a moderator flag asking for question migration, and it has already attracted another "off-topic" close vote after being reopened.  The original close history was wiped out by the failed migration.

Comment: I have multiple personalities... they are all Abraham Lincoln

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was my bug.  It happened because we have a unique constraint on a question's tags, i.e. a tag may only appear once on any given question.

During the migration, the [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) tag, which is a synonym of [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) on Unix & Linux, was replaced with its master, making [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) appear twice on the migrated question.

Boom!

This has been fixed and will be deployed shortly.

Comment: Cool bug! I gave you 25 magical meta credits for your trouble.

Comment: Unfortunately some traces of problems have been left: take a look at the edit history of the question. Apparently Robert voted to close (as a diamond mod) multiple times for each closure: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4975647/revisions